# Функции в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Я полный профан в `laravel`, и сейчас бьюсь вот с какой задачей

У меня была функция `1.php`:

```
    require_once('include/config.php');
      require_once('include/func.php');
      require_once('include/class_header.php');

      function GPSOnline ($gpsonline){
      $gpsonline= getHTTPGPSOnline();
      $fstep = explode("|", $gpsonline);
      foreach($fstep as $k => $v){
        if(strlen($v)>0){
            $sstep [] = explode(",", $v);// создаем 2у мерный массив

            }
    }
        $array = array();
        foreach ($sstep as $v){
        $tmp['login'] = $v[0];
        $tmp['ch'] = substr($v[0],0,1);
        $tmp['poz'] = substr($v[0],1);
        $tmp['la'] = $v[1];
        $tmp['lo'] = $v[2];
        $array[] = $tmp;// ключем нового многомерного масиива явлеться 0 элемент массива $sstep 
    } 
     echo json_encode($array);
    }}
     GPSOnline();
```

Все отлично работает и выдает мне нужные данные!
Далее к этой функции обращался AJAX запрос в параметрах которого был указано:

```
  url: "/1.php"
```

**Вопрос**: Как мне мою функцию `1.php` перенести в новый созданный метод в фреймворке laravel и поменять значение url в AJAX запросе(т.е. поменять `url: "/1.php"` на `url:"ссылка на метод laravel"`?

Посидев на форумах я прописал новый класс и добавил в него метод:

```
     public function GPSOnline () {
       $gpsonline=File::get( Config::get('app.driverspath'));
       $fstep = explode("|", $gpsonline);
             foreach($fstep as $k => $v){
              if(strlen($v)>0){
               $sstep [] = explode(",", $v);
               }
             }
            $array = array();
             foreach ($sstep as $v){
              $tmp['ch'] = substr($v[0],0,1);
              $tmp['poz'] = substr($v[0],1);
              $tmp['la'] = $v[1];
              $tmp['lo'] = $v[2];
              $array[] = $tmp;

             } 
             // echo json_encode($array);
              return Response::json(array($array));

             }
```

В AJAX запросе я в источник url прописал:

```
url:"{{URL::action('GpsController@GPSOnline')}}"
```

Но все равно не работает, мне кажется я не корректно прописал метод `GPSOnline`?!

Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Неужели никто не знает?

Answer (score 1):

- для начала разберись со своими функциями - с помощью composer добавь свои файлы в автозагрузку или сделай рефакторинг кода файлов которые инклюдятся и создай класс на основе своих функций;
- создай `сontroller/action` в котором используй функционал получившегося кода;
- далее создай route в `app/routes.php` с `url` по которому будет идти обращение к твоему `controller/action`:

  ```
  Route::ajax('some/route', 'ControllerName@ActionName');
  ```

в принципе всё

Comment: Спасибо товарищ!  Я немного видоизменил тему, можешь пожалуйста посомтреть и помочь?

Comment: я перенес тему в http://hashcode.ru/questions/265218/php-laravel-4-%D0%B8-json

Answer (score 1):

1. проверит маршрут в роуте(80% ошибок имено там!)
2. Обязательно выполнят проверки, ибо метод `File::get` если файл пустой вернет `NULL`!

В итоге:

```
 public function GPSOnline () {
   $gpsonline=File::get( Config::get('app.driverspath'));
   $tmp=array();  
   $sstep=array();
   if ($gpsonline != NULL){
   $fstep = explode("|", $gpsonline);
         foreach($fstep as $k => $v){

          if(strlen($v)>0){
           $sstep [] = explode(",", $v);
           }

         }
        $array = array();
         foreach ($sstep as $v){
          if(isset ($v[0])&&($v[1])&&($v[2])){
          $tmp['ch'] = substr($v[0],0,1);
          $tmp['poz'] = substr($v[0],1);
          $tmp['la'] = $v[1];
          $tmp['lo'] = $v[2];
          $array[] = $tmp;
          } 
         } 
          return Response::json($array);
          }
         else {
            return Response::json (array());
         }
        }
```